# Can I give a ConstraintLayout a "hidden" variable?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am using Kotlin, XML, and android studio.

I have a ConstraintLayout that I am using as a "button". The user will click it and it will bring them to somewhere else. They are procedural generated into a recyclerview thus I can't hardcore data into them. On their creation, is there a way to give them a "hidden" variable that I can reference when they are clicked. If I was using a button, I would just set the text to this value and then reference its text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the layout an id which you can use as reference to find that view.

Here is some example code

```kotlin
class MyAdapter():RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>() {

 override fun onCreateView()

 override fun onBindView(holder:VH, position:Int):VH {
    holder.layout.setOnClickListener {
       //do something when view is clicked
    }
 }
 
 class VH(view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
   //here you can get a reference to your layout
   val layout = view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.someId)
 }
```

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    andoid:id="@+id/someId" <----- This is the important bit here
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Header" />
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `View.setId()` when you generate the layout - there's even a handy [`generateViewId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#generateViewId()) function that will produce one for you, that's guaranteed not to clash with any IDs you've already defined in the `R` file

But as well, the [`onClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View)) method in a `View.OnClickListener` passes in the view that was clicked as a parameter, so maybe you don't need to look anything up? If you're using a lambda, it's implicitly passed in as `it` (since it's a single parameter) so you might not realise it's there, but you can explicitly name it as `view` or whatever

```
layout.setOnClickListener { view -> ... }
```

but if it's all procedural, maybe just use a function?

```
fun onLayoutClick(layout: View) { ... }
...
layout.setOnClickListener(::onLayoutClick)
```

the function has the same signature (same parameters and return type) as the lambda so you can just throw in the function reference like that

Comment: I did a similar thing to solve my issue, thanks!